# What level of heat is best when caramelizing?

Tags: sauce, temperature, caramelization

When you caramelize onions, carrots or mushrooms - what is the best heat level for the fire? Or rather - what should be the temperature of the oil where you can caramelize the food quickly yet not burn it on the sides too much?

Answer (score 4):

In my personal experience, "caramelizing" and "quickly" are not things that get along well. I happen to have done a small batch of caramelized onions last night. It took two hours, which is faster than some larger batches I have done, but not anything I'd call "quick" - quick leads to burnt onions, not caramelized ones, in my experience. So - low heat, and forget "quickly."

Comment: Tricks using salt, sugar or soda exist, and these might or might not yield a good enough result for a sauce... worth mentioning, but doesn't concern the temperature choice.